# String Manipulation In C# - Last Index Of

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am processing a string in a chat system. I have added the attribute wrap="hard" to the textarea where the string is entered, but the browser is not adding a line return when the string wraps to the next line.

I have tried this but it's not working for some reason.

```
string message = null;
string[] messageLines = commMessage.Split('\n');

foreach (string messageLine in messageLines)
{
    if (messageLine.Length > 60)
    {
         messageLine.Insert(messageLine.LastIndexOf(' ', 60), "\n");
    }

    message += messageLine;
}
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the string's `Insert()` method does not modify the original string, in returns the new string.  Use the return value of that method.

See the documentation for the [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

You can do something like this:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
string[] messageLines = commMessage.Split('\n');

foreach (string messageLine in messageLines)
{
    if (messageLine.Length > 60)
    {
         message.Append(messageLine.Insert(messageLine.LastIndexOf(' ', 60), "\n"));
    }
    else
    {
         message.Append(messageLine);
    }
}

// do something with message.ToString()
```